# How to tell if Angular is finished loading

Tags: angularjs

Is there something I can type into the chrome javascript console that will tell me if Angular is finished loading? I'm not looking for an event that fires when it's loaded, I'm looking for a property that I can inspect afterwards.

Comment: Hope the ngInit directive to angular controller can help

Comment: If all else fails, you could just set a property inside the event handler.

Comment: Finished loading in what way? The script? If the app bootstrapping is done?

Comment: I mean it in the most general way. When the page is ready to be looked at by a human or screenshot.